FSYNC: File write plus fsync
Suppose I have a file open and I want to write to file and then fsync. Would it be equivalent to, say like I open the same file in 2 places and write to one and then sequentially do fsync to other?
One additional thing I would like to know, suppose I am looping over 100k data and appending it one by one in a file and programming language allows me to write async code. If I am synchronously writing to a file and then asynchronously calling fsync. Does asynchronous fsync does not have any advantage because it is in loop and file will wait for last fsync to happen?
